# Call method on every object who has interface

Tags: c#

Ok, let's say I have an interface Motor

```
public interface Motor 
{
    void PressGas();
}
```

And I have multiple classes who has the Motor interface

```
public class Car : Motor
{
    public Car() {}
    public void PressGas() 
    { 
        //Press gas as car
    }
}


public class Plane : Motor
{
    public Plane() {}
    void PressGas() 
    {
        //Press gas as plane
    }
}
```

And I create multiple of these objects

```
Plane plane1 = new Plane();
Plane plane2 = new Plane();
Car car1 = new Car();
Car car2 = new Car();
```

Now, I want to use the interface to call `PressGas()` on every object who has the interface. Is there a way to do it without adding all objects to a list and going through the list?

Comment: Neither of your classes implement the `Motor` interface though?  Besides that I am not entirely sure what you are even asking.  You might want to try clarifying with an edit

Comment: As pointed out by @maccettura, an edit will be nice. However, if I got you correctly, you can create, for instance, a motor list `List<Motor>`. Then add all the objects that implements the Motor interface to the the list created. You can then loop through the list to get what you want.

Comment: This does not make much sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Best practice is to preface an interface with the letter I. For example: IMotor

Comment: What happens if you call `PressGas` on an electric motor? Should it be something like `Accelerate` instead? ;)

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you need your classes to inherit the interface:

```
public class Car : Motor
{
    public void PressGas() { }
}

public class Plane : Motor
{
    public void PressGas() { }
}
```

Now is the tricky part, if you don't want to use a `List<Motor>`, the easiest way to do this is to create a method:

```
public static void CallPressGas(params Motor[] motors)
{
    //Here you can iterate through them:
    foreach (var motor in motors)
        motor.PressGas();

    //Or if you wanted to use a list (even though you said you didn't)
    motors.ToList().ForEach(m => m.PressGas());
}
```

Which you could then call like this:

```
CallPressGas(plane1, plane2, car1, car2);
```

*As a pilot I have a hard time with a method in `Plane` called `PressGas`...*

Comment: He wants to do it without keeping a list of the objects.

Comment: @StevenB. I missed that, I updated with an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

First, In C# interface implementation has to be explicitly declared. It can't be inferred just because there are signatures that match (dynamic type excluding).

Second, if you don't want to create a list of type , for whatever reason, you can use reflection to go through fields of type. I would only use this as a last resort or some corner/weird case. This example only works for fields

```
public class CompositionTest
{
    Plane plane1 = new Plane();
    Plane plane2 = new Plane();
    Car car1 = new Car();
    Car car2 = new Car();

    public CompositionTest()
    {

        var imotorFields = GetType().GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(field => typeof(IMotor).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType));

        foreach (var field in imotorFields)
        {
            ((IMotor)field.GetValue(this)).PressGas();
        }
    }
}

public interface IMotor
{
    void PressGas();
}

public class Car : IMotor
{
    public Car() { }
    public void PressGas()
    {
        //Press gas as car
    }
}


public class Plane : IMotor
{
    public Plane() { }
    public void PressGas()
    {
        //Press gas as plane
    }
}
```